# how to send delete request without knowing the id in json?

Tags: json, api, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

for example
if i have used findByEmail my url will look something like this
    http://localhost:8080/api/carts/search/findByEmail?email=helloworld@gmail.com

how will the URL for delete request look if i have deleteByEmail in JPA repository

this is how my JPA looks like

```
public interface CartRepository extends JpaRepository<Cart, Integer> {

    @Transactional
    @RestResource(exported = true)
    List<Cart> deleteByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: the link for delete request look like this http://localhost:8080/api/carts/Delete/deleteByEmail ?email=helloworld@gmail.com

Comment: @MarwenJaffel i tried that it shows 404 resource not fount error

Answer (score 0):

You can have a rest API as http://localhost:8080/api/carts/email/{emailId} with emailId in PathVariable HttpMethod as DELETE. Inside the service method, you search by emailId and then Delete it using the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a controller method with the appropriate mapping. You can define any URL you want, I used `/api/carts/{email}`. Make sure to send a HTTP DELETE request.

```
@RestController
public class CartController {

    private final CartRepository cartRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CartController (CartRepository cartRepository) {
        this.cartRepository = cartRepository;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/api/carts/{email}")
    public void deleteCart(@PathVariable String email) {
        cartRepository.deleteByEmail(email);
    }

}
```

If you prefer to solve this with a request param, change the `deleteCart` method as shown below:

```
    @DeleteMapping("/api/carts")
    public void deleteCart(@RequestParam String email) {
        cartRepository.deleteByEmail(email);
    }
```